# Is there any reason not to randomly generate the JWT signing key on app start?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mobile, cryptography, jwt

I've been learning about JWT and am attempting to use it for a Web Api application i'm building. The app is only ever going to be small and JWT is probably over kill for it, so scale isn't especially an issue here.

The app needs a signing key to make JWT work and that is currently loaded on app start from the app settings file. That's fine as it goes, but if I distribute the server to other people to run they will need to set their own signing key up.

Is there any reason the app cannot (using a cryptographicly secure RNG) generate its JWT signing key on app start and generate a new one each time it is started? Is there some security problem I am missing thinking this is a way to go?

The immediate downside I can think of is that any current JWT will no longer be valid on restart. But if they have 30 minute lifetimes (or less) and refresh tokens are how you get more (and those are not thrown away on restart) then I don't think that will be a problem. The key will be refreshed early if the server is restarted. So potentially a little extra overhead once after a server restart.

The other downside I can think of is that the user side will need to get a new key on restart to be able to verify the signature on the key. But that didn't seem to be something that was typically done anyway.

The auth server is built into the rest of the server so the key for signing and checking would already be running in the same service. So key distribution wouldn't be a problem.

Am I missing something? Because I hadn't seen the idea suggested anywhere either saying "hey this works" or "oh dear god no you will destroy the universe!".

Am I missing something?

Comment: I'll give you a hint at another problem: we run 3 replicas of our JWT-protected web API. A given request will randomly hit one of the three. We also run blue/green deployments, so it would be pretty annoying each time we deploy an update if everyone's keys got invalidated, or even when Kubernetes decides to recycle a pod.

Comment: I can see why that would be an issue. That makes perfect sense to not randomly generate a signing key in that case. What im doing is never going to run at that sort of scale. It is a personal audiobook server. But thanks I hadn't heard of blue gree deployment. Learned something new.